# adding default values within javascript custom function

Tags: javascript, function

mmorning, im a php man so I cant understand why this is throwing an error:

```
function display_message( bool, msg, remove_wrap = false ) {
    if( bool === true ) {
        error = get_msg( msg, remove_wrap );
    }else{
        error = get_error_msg( msg, remove_wrap );
    }
    $.fancybox( error, { 'autoDimensions' : false, 'width' : 450, 'height' : 'auto', 'transitionIn' : 'none', 'transitionOut' : 'none' });
}
```

the culprit being 'remove_wrap = false' from the function.

can anyone tell me what i should be writing here. regards, phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function display_message( bool, msg, remove_wrap ) {
    remove_wrap = remove_wrap === true;
    if( bool === true ) {
        error = get_msg( msg, remove_wrap );
    }else{
        error = get_error_msg( msg, remove_wrap );
    }
    $.fancybox( error, { 'autoDimensions' : false, 'width' : 450, 'height' : 'auto', 'transitionIn' : 'none', 'transitionOut' : 'none' });
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much the solution /i came to after the first post (without the example) so theremore i must accept as answer, thanks for everyone who game an answer all do the job.

Comment: Second line could be reduced to `remove_wrap = remove_wrap === true;`

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript doesn't support argument defaults like that. Like many other have said, you can pick a default inside your function. A concise idiom for setting a default value is:

```
arg = arg || default;
```

So, in your case it would be:

```
remove_wrap = remove_wrap || false;
```

However, if your default value is `false`, you don't even need to set it. Because, when that argument is lacking, its value will be of type `undefined` inside the function and that value is already "falsy": you can directly use `remove_wrap` as it is:

```
function display_message(bool, msg, remove_wrap) {
    var error = bool
        ? get_msg(msg, remove_wrap)
        : get_error_msg(msg, remove_wrap);

    $.fancybox(error, {
        autoDimensions: false,
        width: 450,
        height: "auto",
        transitionIn: "none",
        transitionOut: "none"
    });
}
```

**Bonus:**
Note that I've also added a `var` to the `error` variable (don't omit the var unless your true intention is to create a global variable). I've also shortened the assignment with a ternary expression. I've also reformatted the `fancybox` call with a syntax that most people find more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're a PHP man, this might come in handy. Coming from JS myself, I actually messed up a couple of times, assuming this was in the language:

```
function (some_var) {
    some_var = some_var || 'default';
}
```

In PHP, the "or" operator will return "true" if the first value or second values are true, otherwise "false."

But in JavaScript, the "or" operator actually returns the *first value itself*, if it's truthy. <strike>It only returns `false` if both values are falsy.</strike> If both values are falsy, then it returns *the second value.* That means that the above is a super efficient way of assigning defaults.

My sincerest apologies if this was all old knowledge. I just wish someone had walked *me* through when I was switching languages.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot supply default values to javascript function parameters, but you can leave them undefined and then assign a default at the beginning of your function.

For example:

```
function display_message( bool, msg, remove_wrap ) { 
    if(undefined === remove_wrap) 
        remove_wrap = false;

    //Rest of function
}
```

Call this function like this: `display_message(true, "my msg");`

Answer (score 1):

You can handle default values like this:

```
function display_message(bool, msg, remove_wrap) {
    if (remove_wrap == null) remove_wrap = false;
    // rest of your code...

}
```

The default value will be applied if the function is called with either:

```
display_message(some_bool, some_msg);
// Or,
display_message(some_bool, some_msg, null);
```

Comparing to `null` is handy because it allows the caller to explicity ask for the default value, but it isn't prone to overriding `0` or `''` (empty string) like a simple falsy comparison would.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
function display_message( bool, msg, remove_wrap) {
  if(remove_wrap === undefined) {
    var remove_wrap = false;
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare default values within the parameter section of your function declaration.  Instead, to declare defaults your function declaration should look like this:

```
function display_message( bool, msg, remove_wrap ) {
  remove_wrap = remove_wrap || false;
  // rest of code
}
```

Thus, if remove_wrap is defined it will stay equal to itself, but if it is undefined it will be set to false.